# Airflow 1.10.0 | ImportError: No module named pip._vendor

Tags: airflow

I am trying to install airflow 1.10.0 in AWS EC2 server. I am getting below error.

My command to install the airflow is:-
`SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes pip install apache-airflow==1.10.0`

```
 Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/a5/9fc15751f9725923b170ad37d6c61031fc9e941bafd5288ca6ee51233284/pendulum-1.4.4.tar.gz (74kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 29.1MB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp4EPg6U:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 197, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 54, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-bmBubo/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 115, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return _get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-bmBubo/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 101, in _get_build_requires
      _run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-bmBubo/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 85, in _run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 47, in <module>
      from build import *
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/build.py", line 7, in <module>
      from pip._vendor import pytoml
  ImportError: No module named pip._vendor

  ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp4EPg6U" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-whVmak/pendulum
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `pip` or run the following code:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources
sudo pacman -S python-setuptools python-pip
```